# Speedup of simulation is greater than optimum

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I parallelized a hydrodynamics simulation in C++ with OpenMP. I use an Intel CPU that has 4 cores and 8 threads to run my simulations. I have noticed that the speedup is greater than I would expect (see image).[image]

I would expect that the speedup of using 8 threads when using a 4 core CPU should be smaller or equal to 4. But the speedup is greater than 4.5. How is that possible? Isn't the ideal curve a line that goes from (1,1) to (8,4)?

Comment: The ideal is (1,1) to (8,8).  But unlikely on a hyper-threaded core.

Comment: Definitely not. If your code made optimal use of memory and avoided all cache misses you could expect a line from (1,1) to (4,4) and then possibly some degradation as there would be no benefit from using HT. However, if that is not the case, you may see improved performance from HT when a thread waits for memory to be loaded, the other thread on the same core takes over and does some work etc.

Comment: We could give you a much better answer if your question included a [mcve] and a more specific hardware description.

Comment: @Zulan It would be very difficult to reduce my hydrodynamics simulation to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please also see https://superuser.com/q/279629/68031 for a generic answer to your question. One more thing to consider: A speedup from HyperThreading can indicate that your application uses hardware resources inefficiently. You might be able to gain much more performance from optimization of memory access patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(8, 4) is the minimum (lets ignore the OS and other processes) that you should see.  If you have 4 cores then you should be able to use all of the them allowing you to process 4 times the data.  Since you have hyper-threading though you can potentially do better.  If your threads aren't busy all of time then you can leverage that down time buy running another thread on that core.  Depending on how busy the threads are this can be a very minimal improvement or a very large one.

Taking all of that together (8, 4.5) is a very possible result and the reason that it isn't higher is it takes time to switch context and you have an OS and other process running that will also need to access the CPU at points during the execution.

Comment: Giving (8,4) as "minimum" is a dangerously misleading simplification. There is large range of common reasons for getting Speedup < 4 at 8 or 4 threads. I can't see how considering "threads aren't busy all of time" provides any meaningful insight into *why* HT *can* improve performance (without giving any indication as to what *busy* means). Further, "time to switch context and [...] OS and other process running" are **not** the primary reason performance isn't even better. The reason is mainly utilization of shared resources by the simulation tasks.